# The out parameter must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
       else
  strPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/" + strFileToUpload + strVendorNo), fileName);

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPath))
                                {
                                    strReturnMssg = strPath;
                                    fileItem.SaveAs(strPath);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                                else


         strReturnMessage = "Selected file should be less than 5ΜB.";
                                }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<!--" + ex.Message + "-->");
        }

        return strReturnMssg;
    }
```

not able to send attach files to server only path is going
getting an error in Error   11  The out parameter 'strReturnMessage' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Comment: It would be great if we could see: 1 - the actual method paramters to find out what your `out` variable is. 2 - formatting that doesn't make my eyes bleed. 3 - for you to actually read the error message, which clearly tells you how to handle the situation

Answer (score 0):

Your return message variable seems not the be defined when an error occurs in your try-catch block. Simply setting strReturnMssg = string.Empty or a default value at the beginning of your method should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you haven't assigned a value to your `out` parameter at some scope before you leave the method. For example:

```
bool TrySomeMethod(bool someCondition, out int someValue)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        someValue = 1;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Will give you the same compile time error because `someValue` has not been assigned to before the return statement in the else statement.

To fix this you can assign a value before your return:

```
someValue = -1;
return false;
```

or at the top of your method you can assign some default value to the `out` parameter i.e.

```
someValue = -1;
if (someCondition)
//....
```

However with this approach you must be careful to set the `out` parameter to what you want it to be if successful as no error is thrown i.e.

```
bool TrySomeMethod(bool someCondition, out int someValue)
{
    someValue = -1;
    if (someCondition)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That will compile fine but there is a logic problem as `someValue` is never set to `1` inside of the if-statement.

Note that in your particular case your method wants `strReturnMessage` to be an `out` parameter and you are also returning a very similarly named variable from the method `strReturnMssg`. If you need two return messages something isn't quite right with your logic.